# Naming convention for Rails models based on existing tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models. Users and Jobs. I have a join table to indicate a User's interest in a Job. I was using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship for Users and Jobs. I now realize I need to be using a has_many :through relationship. Because of that, I need to have a model for my join table or I get `undefined Constant` errors. My join table is called `jobs_users`. What should I name the `.rb` file for the model and what should the class name be in order to get Rails magic to work? I have found SO questions that imply the class should be `JobUser`, but nothing on what the `.rb` file should be named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Naming convention for Rails models based on existing tables

Model class names use `CamelCase`. These are singular, and will map automatically to the plural database table name.

```
 > 'JobsUser'.underscore
=> "jobs_user"
```

This means your file should be named `jobs_user.rb`. And class will look like below

```
class JobsUser < ApplicationRecord
  ...........
end
```

---

For fresh migration, you can rollback and destroy current table migration e.g `jobs_users` and then run this command

```
rails g model UserJob user:references job:references
```

`db/migrate/TIMESTAMP_create_user_jobs.rb` file looks like below

```
class CreateUserJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :user_jobs do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :job, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then migrate this and created model file name is `user_job.rb`

`has_many :through` relationship will looks like this

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, through: :user_jobs
end

#job.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :user_jobs, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :users, through: :user_jobs
end

#user_job.rb
class UserJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

That's it

Comment: I dropped the old join table and created a new one this way and it worked perfectly, thank you!